# How to loop through store and count a fields data on sencha

Tags: javascript, mysql, extjs

I have a store in sencha with the following code

```
Ext.define('Qvidi.store.MyJsonStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'Qvidi.model.Qvidi',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        storeId: 'MyJsonStore',
        model: 'Qvidi.model.Qvidi',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            extraParams: {
                class: 'Qvidi',
                method: 'getData'
            },
            url: 'server/index.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'results'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
  }
});
```

I need to loop throug the store and count a field called gender coming from a mysql databas, the database is loaded and retrieving data, however I need to iterate through the data to count how many males and females are in the database. So males is defined as one in the database and females are defined as 2. All this data is loaded into the store.

I just need to know how to distinguish between the males and females. I know you must use the foreach function in sencha.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Write a code  store after load

```
yourStore.queryBy(function(record,id){ return (record.get('Your Field name') === "male/female"); }).getCount(); // For male/female
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of `filter()` & `getCount()` function of store to achieve this:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('MyJsonStore');
store.filter('gender',1);       //filtering all male records
var maleCount = store.getCount();    //getting the count
store.clearFilter();
store.filter('gender',2);           //filtering all female records
var femaleCount=store.getCount();
store.clearFilter();
```

Comment: I tried that but halfway through I found another way, I decided to actually write a very specific SQL query that formed the data the way I needed it to be

Comment: So I didnt need to filter through the store

Comment: Thank you for the assistance